# Handling 404 error in ASP.NET Web Forms with URL Routing

Tags: asp.net, webforms, http-status-code-404, url-routing

I'm looking at implementing URL Routing on an ASP.NET Web Forms website and have been looking at the best way to handle 404 errors so for example:

```
routes.MapPageRoute("NewsRouteArticle", "news/article/{url}", "~/news.aspx")
```

The URL is matched against a news article in the database.

What happens if a news article no longer exists? How can a handle this and redirect the user to the Custom Error page?

I have been reading about `Throw New HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound)` but it looks like it is for ASP.NET Web API.

I'm also aware of the issue that exists with ASP.NET where 404 Errors actually gives a status code of 302 and I want to try and avoid the issue (see [this](http://imar.spaanjaars.com/497/proper-handling-of-404-errors-using-redirectmode)).

Answer (score 1):

One good reason to use ASP.NET.MVC, I have not done anything in webforms for so long, but I used

Server.TransferRequest("/my404page.aspx")

This stopped the 2 requests and the 302 to 404 problem

then returned a 404

```
   Response.Clear()
    Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = True
    Response.StatusCode = 404
```

Hope that helps